# How to fix the typeError when plotting categorical data using Python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, python-3.7

I am trying to visualize my data using Python 3.7 with Pandas and Seaborn but I keep getting errors, please can you explain to me whats really wrong. I have tried researching online and implementing but I keep getting different errors that prevent me from visualizing the data

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

from matplotlib import rcParams
from pylab import rcParams
import pylab as plt
import seaborn as sb


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

Happiness_data = pd.read_csv('happiness-cantril-ladder.csv')
Happiness_data.columns = ['Entity','Code','Year','World Happiness Report']
Entity = Happiness_data['Entity']

sb.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

sb.catplot(x='Entity', kind="box", data=Happiness_data)
sb.catplot(y='Entity', hue="hls", kind="bar", data=Happiness_data)

plt.show()
```

Here are the errors:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1601, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 3670, in boxplot
    labels=labels, autorange=autorange)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1285, in boxplot_stats
    stats['mean'] = np.mean(x)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3118, in mean
out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 87, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of your input data set?